# Need suggestion about Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I am about to start very big project with PHP which will have millions of databse records.

So I planned to use Laravel framework.

So can anyone share his experience of Laravel. Am I using correct framework for such a big a project?

I need better performance and easy to manage, update etc.

We have all powerful resources like servers etc. Just need opinion about framework.

I can develop anything with core PHP but don't know much about Laravel.

Also please suggest if any other framework fits with my requirements.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with this link and see the benchmark : http://systemsarchitect.net/2013/04/23/performance-benchmark-of-popular-php-frameworks/

Laravel is definitely awesome framework. As there are lots of built in libraries. Laravel has a growing community, it also has some features like migration generations.If performance doesn't matter you might as well use laravel. But, if you are at all concerned about the speed of your application, then i would suggest phalcon.

From internet :

> Laravel is PHP source base just like most of php frameworks out there;
>   Phalcon is different, it is delivered as a php extension, which will
>   be injected into the php core while running. So, you can just download
>   the extension on Windows, or rebuild it, enable it in php.ini, and
>   after that you got a high performance framework working. For Laravel,
>   you have to pull A LOT of other packages through composer. Laravel is
>   trying to wrap many great packages and give them nice API wrappers on
>   top, so you can work with them conveniently. Phalcon is faster, but
>   you have to do more works with it than in Laravel to make the same
>   thing.

I personally suggest you Phalcon as far as speed is concern.

And the main important thing is your coding style. If your code and mysql queries are not optimized then no framework will help you.

Comment: I love this. No code nothing just a framework in RAM and we can develop own project structure as we like.